# JPARepository autowired giving null in service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am creating a web application using Spring boot and JPA.
When I tried debugging the below code, I could see that inside the service, the repository is null. I haven't done an explicit **new** call for either the service or the repository. I am not sure why this is happening.

The userService seems to have been created fine, but the repository inside it is null.

The exception stack trace I have pasted here is for the call to controller's `addUser()`

**Controller**

```
    @RestController
    public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addUser(@RequestBody final User user) {
        userService.addUser(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{email}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void updateUser(@RequestBody final User user, @PathVariable final String email) {
        if (loginService.isUserAuthentic(user) && user.getEmail().equals(email)) {
            userService.updateUser(user);
        } else {
            throw new AuthenticationFailureException("The user is not authenticated to view records",
                    HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{email}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteUser(@RequestBody final User user, @PathVariable final String email) {
        if (loginService.isUserAuthentic(user) && user.getEmail().equals(email)) {
            userService.deleteUser(email);
        } else {
            throw new AuthenticationFailureException("The user is not authenticated to view records",
                    HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private static final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoder.getPasswordEncoder();

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    /*@Autowired
    private RecordRepository recordRepository;
    */

    public final List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> allUsers = new LinkedList<User>();
        userRepository.findAll().forEach(allUsers::add);
        return allUsers;
    }

    public final void addUser(final User user) {
        if (UserFieldValidations.isValidEmail(user.getEmail())) {
            user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            user.setRole(UserRole.USER);
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }

    public final void updateUser(final User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public final List<User> search(Specification<User> spec) {
        return userRepository.findAll(spec);
    }
```

***Line 41***

```
userRepository.save(user);
```

***Repository***

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

}
```

**Entity**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {

    private String name;
    @Id
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserRole role;
    private Instant instant;

}
```

***ApplicationMain***

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.nishitp"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.nishitp.repository")
@EntityScan("com.nishitp.beans")
public class ToptalCaloriesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ToptalCaloriesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.nishitp.service.UserService.addUser(UserService.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.nishitp.controller.UserController.addUser(UserController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: which version of spring-boot and spring-data are you using?

Comment: where is this from `UserFieldValidations` in `UserService`? and can you highlight line number `41` in `UserService`

Comment: I am assuming your repository is in the package you mentioned in `@EnableJpaRepositories`. Can you try removing `@Repository` annotation? I’m just curious.

Comment: @krishnaPrasad spring boot 2.2.2 and spring-data 2.2.3

Comment: @Deadpool UserFieldValidations is a utility class and isValidEmail is a static method in that class. All that does is checks if the given string follows a regex for the email address. Also, have edited the question to clearly mark the line.

Comment: @SunilDabburi  Yes the class is in the correct package. Removed the repository annotation, still, the same error.

Comment: Ok. Can you remove `JpaSpecificationExecutor` and see?

Comment: @SunilDabburi I need JpaSpecificationExecutor

Comment: I think everything fine. Try by running with debug mode.